# iOS - Requested Certificate revocation - now what?

Tags: ios, objective-c, provisioning-profile, enterprise, ad-hoc-distribution

I've been working on an app I inherited from another developer, and have gotten it to the point where I want to generate an ipa file. I created the archive, but when I try to export it as ad-hoc, I get the message "Your account already has a valid iOS distribution certificate".

Here's the kicker - I chose the company account to select a development team to use for provisioning. I clicked into "view details", and somehow managed to bring up a dialog box which offered the option to revoke the certificate and generate a new one.

I clicked "yes", and got a message that the certificate had been revoked, and a certificate request had been generated. I also clicked "+" on the iOS development entry, and it seems to have updated all the provisioning profiles to a year from today.

However, when I look through the certificates and provisioning profiles in the apple developer portal, none of them have been revoked.

My question is,

1) is anything going to be revoked that will affect existing apps that have already been distributed?

2) If so how to remedy the situation?

3) Where is the csr?

4) How to generate the ad-hoc ipa?

Comment: I'm curious what they told you on the phone. At first glance I would have guessed one of the two Distribution certs had been revoked so that it could be renewed for its 3 year renewal.

Comment: They couldn't find anything revoked. He said it was weird that he didn't see anything revoked. He suggested that I just revoke the certificate through the site and re-request it. I haven't done it yet, though.

Comment: I chalk up XCode and the Apple Portal as the same as being hungry while trying to grocery shop: you have no idea what you want to buy and the outcome is always random.

Comment: That's a relief. I really just feel like revoking and re-requesting the certification and provisioning profile. But, this is my first time doing on my company's account and don't want to screw it up. I'm still unclear on the exact details of the process, so I'm hesitant to try it. But I'd like to get it out of the way. It's an Enterprise account, btw.

Comment: Yes, that was my question. I turns out that if you just want to release apps internally, you can get an Enterprise account, for $300. It's similar to a standard developer account, but you can't release apps on it to the App Store. It's good for testing, too, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem recently, call apple with this number and they will be glad to help you... 1-800-633-2152

Answer (score 1):

I'm the agent for my company's Enterprise account. DO NOT revoke your Enterprise cert if it's tied to any provisioning profiles with which apps were signed and are actively deployed. Doing that will render all of those apps unusable as they will crash upon being launched.

What you can do, assuming you have only created one Enterprise Distribution Cert, is create a second cert in your portal via another CSR then tie it to the provisioning profiles you're looking to compile with.

If you already have two Enterprise Distribution certs and they're both tied to active applications you're about to have to make a tough decision...

Comment: Thanks. Yes, there are two Enterprise distribution certs. Is that the limit? And how can you tell which apps they're associated with?

Comment: You're going to have to look at their expiration dates then drill into every **active** Enterprise Distribution Provisioning Profile you have in the portal via edit. Jot down which apps are tied to which cert and hope there isn't a mix between each cert.

If there is a mix you may have to do a re-release of your apps immediately after revoking one of the certs. What happens is the device will phone home to Apple to check the validity of the apps running under your Enterprise account. If it detects a revoked/expired cert the app is toast until you release a new version with a valid cert.

Comment: We have 3 apps, which are all distributed through the app store. So, I'm guessing the Enterprise account was set up for testing purposes.

Comment: It should be a completely different portal than your App Store account (ie: Enterprise vs Company). If that's the case you're good to revoke that Enterprise Cert (per the above stipulations). If it's your Company (App Store) account I'm not a good resource for the repercussions of revoking that cert, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for you help, Dan. I *finally* got it working, by doing the following: 1) Import the developer profiles from the other machine, which loaded the certificate I needed with the secret key. 2) Rename the app bundle to the enterprise name (it was named under the app store name). 3) Change the team name in the "General" to my company's team - it was defaulting to my personal developer accounts team! With these changes, I could export an ipa as both ad-hoc and enterprise, upload it to Hockey Rink, and download it on my phone.

Comment: Great to hear. I'd also test the install on a device that is NOT registered in your portal as a control test :)